# Error: field is required

Tags: database, laravel-5.1

I have done a code, in which i create events. When i create event there was a field named "detailed_address" which i have removed now, from database, from model,from the edit page, from every where.

Creating an event works fine. but when i edit that event and save it, there is error as:

> The detailed address field is required.

I have checked my code for at-least 5 times there is no word detailed address now used.

controller methods:

```
    public function update(EventRequest $request, $id)
{
    $event = Event::findOrFail($id);
    $input = $request->all();
    $input['days_of_week'] = serialize(Input::get('days_of_week'));
    $query = $event->update($input);
    return redirect('event');
}


    public function store(Request $request)
{

    $checkbox = Input::get('days_of_week');
    $checkbox_selection = Input::get('agree');
    $input = $request->all();
    $input['days_of_week'] = serialize($checkbox);
    $query =  Event::create($input);
    return view('event.create');
}
```

Can any one tell what will be my problem?

Comment: Try run `php artisan clear-compiled` then `php artisan optimize`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @manix suggested, try running `php artisan clear-compiled`, then i'd suggest running `php artisan cache:clear` as well just to make doubly sure it's not a cache issue.

Something that could also be worth looking into is your requests folder `(app\http\requests)`, if you weren't validating the input on the controller it was likely being done via requests which might still be checking for input that isn't coming through.

Is the field also still registered as mass assignable on the model?
Can't see why it'd throw a validation error but it's worth making doubly sure it's gone from there too

Comment: Yeh, it was in one of requests, which i forget to check!

Comment: Good stuff glad you sorted it :D